# Form is getting timedout within 10 minutes

Tags: c#, session

I have set session timeout as 120minutes. I have filled the details of the form and I went to some other page and return back to fill the incomplete form and I found that it goes to the login page.

I tried using

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms timeout="120"/>
    </authentication>
```

But it didn't work.

web.config:

```
<Connectionstrings>
</ConnectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="7F962D9FAC5BA3E79A71E722B0FD79BAF52618501DABB750004795CFFDF1AC6BD66BA5FF028DE94730C2FBA150C8A049CC7B35B2CE4CC60BEF0AE47B36CBA5DF" decryptionKey="F6572AF020B96CB22ED4B987E2C0DB0DA6E68493A7F07C6F37F574907F91FDA6" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
    <trace enabled="false" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="15" mostRecent="false"/>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->

    <sessionState timeout="120" cookieless="false" mode="InProc"/>
    <!--<sessionState timeout="120"/>-->
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/expo_crm/user_login.aspx" timeout="60" />
    </authentication>-->

    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <siteMap enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyNewSitemapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/expo_crm/all_reports/admin_report.sitemap"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
  </system.web>
```

I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: `But it dint worked.` **How** did it not work?

Comment: it goes to the login page

Comment: after 10-15 minutes

Comment: `<!--<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/expo_crm/user_login.aspx" timeout="60" />
    </authentication>-->` What happens if you make it **not commented out** and change `60` to `94`?

Comment: @mjwills it throws out some error

Comment: You claimed it timed out after 10 minutes. I made that comment 1 minute ago. How did you test it that quickly?

Comment: Thats why i commented on that...

Comment: just i am filling the details of the form and clicking on save button after 10 minutes....

Comment: @mjwills whatever it may be...i have set the timeout as 120 minutes so it should timeout after 2 hrs...i just tested it and found that it is getting timed out within that time.

Comment: a) When this occurs, are you changing the app (altering the code, building the code and / or altering the web.config) in the 120 minute window? b) What is your IIS app pool recycle time period set to (https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes)? What is your idle time out?

Comment: i m just making changes in the web.config...(session timeout)...

Comment: where to check idle timeout?

Comment: Google for `where to check idle timeout IIS`

Comment: This question appears to have generated a lot of requests for clarification, and they were not merged back into the question. I will assume therefore it is still missing a [mcve], and that it is abandoned.